# Can use F# with web developer express edition

Tags: f#

If i have installed Web developer express in my system and later if i have installed F# SDK in my system, Will i be able to use F# in my web application.
If yes please could you suggest the process to do it.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself, but I think you can't install additional plugins (like the standalone F# integration) to the Express editions of Visual Studio.

However, you can install (free) Visual Studio Shell and install the F# plugin there (see [TryF# web site for detailed information](http://www.tryfsharp.org/Resources/GetNet.aspx)). This can be installed in parallel with Visual Studio Web Express, so at least, you'll be able to create F# project (class library) in one Visual Studio and reference it from a web project in another Visual Studio.

This is a bit cumbersome, but it may be enough to start playing with F# for web development.

(Aside, Microsoft has various programs that make it possible to get developer tools quite cheaply. Students can use *DreamSpark* and new companies can use a program called *BizSpark*)

Comment: I found it as most awesome and powerful language..  Thanks for your answer.. I will concentrate on F# libraries..

Answer (score 1):

Last time I tried, if you try writing F# code to run inside IIS, say an HTTP module, the free tools would refuse to open both the F# project and the C# web project in a single solution. You could still get around it by keeping two studio windows open and copying F# DLLs in custom MSBuild logic on every build to the BIN folder of the web project.